# Build a string inside component.html (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using **@ngx Translate Service**.
Inside a template, you can use it this way, where 'stringName' is a key inside a JSON file:

```
{{ 'stringName.subStringname' | translate }}
```

My problem is that I have to build the key name inside the template, using a string and a variable (whose value is 'subStringname') from the component.ts. I need to build something like this:

```
{{ `stringName.${variable}` | translate }}
```

What's the right synthax?

Comment: ``stringName[variable]`` try like this and check does it works ?

Comment: See here: https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{{ 'stringName.' + variable | translate }}
```